# What's happened to my F1-12?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

I'm a Minecraft player, and recently, I was messing around with the f3 key. Typically, I need to press the function key with it, otherwise it would turn up my volume, but after some spamming because I was bored, it was the other way around. I now need to hold down the function key with f3 to turn up my volume. I cannot see what caused this change. It was clearly something to do with the spamming, but I don't know the exact reason or how to solve it. I should note that this also applies to my other f1-12 keys.

Comment: Nevermind, problem solved.

Comment: Hi Bruce, what solved your problem? If it could be a common problem, you can answer your own question. If it's completely unrelated to Minecraft, you can also simply delete your question.

Comment: This is not game-related. It is a generic computing question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question per BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah's comment.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem is solved but since this could be a common problem, I'm here answering the question. Actually in most keyboards, function keeps are associated with various functions like increasing/decreasing volume or brightness, but by default these functionalities can be accessed while pressing function (fn) key along on the keyboard. [image: Look function key]

Now to the problem you faced, there are function lock keys, activating which the functions of F1-F12 keys become default (i.e. you can just press F1 to mute, you don't need to press Fn along). [image: Fn lock]

So to go back to previous setting just hold the "Fn" key and press "FnLock" key (here Esc). This will solve the problem.